# How to assign an ArrayList to a List?

Tags: list, arraylist, java

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class hello {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Collection c = new ArrayList< Integer >();
    List l = new ArrayList< String >();
  }
}
```

And get the error in the "List l" line:

```
hello.java:6: error: incompatible types
    List l = new ArrayList< String >();
             ^
  required: List
  found:    ArrayList<String>
1 error
```

I am using OpenJDK 1.7:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

**Edit:** When I use `List<String>` that happens:

```
hello.java:6: error: type List does not take parameters
    List< String > l = new ArrayList< String >();
        ^
1 error
```

Comment: List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: remember to match generics, if you use them.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using ? I just get a warning with Java 7.

Comment: Java version is already given: 1.7.0_25 OpenJDK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have checked this line with my OpenJDK `javac`:

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It compiles with no complaints at all.

Based on your second error ("`List` takes no type arguments"), my guess is that you have either a `List` type defined in the same package and it is taking precedence over the JDK type, or you are using more import statements which you did not show, such as

```
import java.awt.*;
```

where that package contains a `List` widget.

Comment: Thanks, there was a List.class fragment from another experiment left. I deleted it, than it worked.

Comment: Yeah there was a 2 min barrier, and an additional coffee break :D

Answer (score 0):

With the same import statements, run the code below and see the which List class you are importing.

```
List l;
System.out.println(l.getClass().getName());
```

Also there might be **List class** defined as inline in the same source file or another java source file like follows: In this case that class will be used:

```
package test;

import java.util.*;  //Implicitly imports java.util.list

class Test {
    List list;       //Not java.util.List type but test.List type
    System.out.println(List.class.getName());  //prints test.List
}

class List {}  //Class defined as inline in the same source file
```